# What's the difference between `usize` and `u32`?

Tags: rust

The documentation says `usize` is

> Operations and constants for pointer-sized unsigned integers.

In most cases, I can replace `usize` with `u32` and nothing happens. So I don't understand why we need two types which are so alike.

Answer (score 205, accepted):

Warning: This answer is legacy for Rust, `usize` have been redefined as "can hold any memory location", see [95228](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/95228) for very deep reasoning, TL;DR: a pointer is not just a number.

---

As the [documentation states](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.usize.html) `usize` is pointer-sized, thus its actual size depends on the architecture you are compiling your program for.

As an example, on a 32 bit x86 computer, `usize = u32`, while on x86_64 computers, `usize = u64`.

`usize` gives you the guarantee to be always big enough to hold any pointer or any offset in a data structure, while `u32` can be too small on some architectures.

Comment: Should I always use `usize` type for safety?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do, if holding indexes in a memory structure, yes. For plain numbers, `u32` is often good. The standard library always use `usize` when appropriate, and rust won't silently convert a `u32` to a `usize`, so you'll see when they are needed.

Comment: `u32` can also be too big if you're working on embedded systems, which Rust as a systems language is designed to work well with. If `u32` was _always_ too small, the language probably would've been designed to silently convert `u32` into `usize`.

Comment: Note that `usize` might cause confusion in cases you are interested in deterministic behavior or serialisation.

Comment: @NicholasPipitone Probably not like `u8` cannot be silently converted to `u16`. But it would've been provided `into()` and not just `try_into()`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Yes, that's more accurate. Had `u32` been guaranteed to be <= `usize` (No embedded systems), then `usize` would've been provided `into()` but not silent conversion. And we get neither bc `usize` can be 8bit, 16bit, 32bit, 64bit, anything~

Answer (score 15):

Adding to @Levans' answer,

The size of **`usize`** is depended on how much size it takes to reference any location in memory.

on a 32 bit target `usize` is 4 bytes and on a 64 bit target `usize` is 8 bytes

Comment: How is this answer different from @Levans' answer?

Comment: I think this answer is a complement to @Leavans's answer. According to the rust documentation, usize is a pointer-sized integer, which means another difference of usize to u32 is, according to this answer.