# Why does usize::max_value() return the maximum value of an unsigned 32 bit integer on 64 bit Windows?

Tags: windows, rust

The [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.usize.html#method.max_value) notes:

> ```
> assert_eq!(usize::max_value(), 18446744073709551615);
> ```

But when I run a simple test:

```
use std::usize;

fn main() {
    println!("{}", usize::max_value());
}
```

It prints: `4294967295`

My project has only been initialised and had the 2 lines `use std::usize;` and `println!("{}", usize::max_value());` added, nothing else has been changed.

My output of `rustc --version --verbose`:

```
rustc 1.41.1 (f3e1a954d 2020-02-24)
binary: rustc
commit-hash: f3e1a954d2ead4e2fc197c7da7d71e6c61bad196
commit-date: 2020-02-24
host: i686-pc-windows-msvc
release: 1.41.1
LLVM version: 9.0
```

After deleting Rust and reinstalling using the 64-bit Windows rustup installer, I get:

```
Current installation options:
  default host triple: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  default toolchain: stable
  profile: default
  modify PATH variable: yes
```

But when I run `rustup toolchain list` it prints a single item:

```
stable-i686-pc-windows-msvc (default)
```

What is happening here?

Comment: If your system really is 64 bit - and if you really want an answer about what is going on - you will need to provide sufficient information for someone to actually answer that question. i.e. system information and exactly how you are compiling and running this program.

Comment: @PeterHall I'm not sure what information I would need to provide, drop a comment and I'll add it (and remember to add information as such in future when having similar questions).

Comment: Documentation may need an improvement, maybe examples can be written with `cfg` annotation

Comment: Also please show which commands you used to compile and run the program.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the documentation for `usize` says:

> The size of this primitive is how many bytes it takes to reference any location in memory. **For example, on a 32 bit target, this is 4 bytes** and on a 64 bit target, this is 8 bytes.

`4294967295` is the maximum size of a 32-bit integer; thus indicating that you are compiling for a 32-bit platform.

This is corroborated by your `rustc` output:

> `host: i686-pc-windows-msvc`

You have installed the 32-bit Windows compiler. The 64-bit compiler says `x86_64-pc-windows-*`.

You can change the default rustup host to 64-bit:

```
rustup set default-host x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
```

You will then probably need to uninstall and reinstall the stable toolchain to switch it to 64-bit.

See also:

- [What's the difference between `usize` and `u32`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29592256/155423)