# Is it possible to get the native CPU size of an integer in Rust?

Tags: optimization, rust, cpu-architecture, bigint

For fun, I'm writing a bignum library in Rust. My goal (as with most bignum libraries) is to make it as efficient as I can. I'd like it to be efficient even on unusual architectures.

It seems intuitive to me that a CPU will perform arithmetic faster on integers with the native number of bits for the architecture (i.e., `u64` for 64-bit machines, `u16` for 16-bit machines, etc.) As such, since I want to create a library that is efficient on all architectures, I need to take the target architecture's native integer size into account. The obvious way to do this would be to use the [cfg attribute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#the-cfg-attribute) *[target_pointer_width](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#target_pointer_width)*. For instance, to define the smallest type which will always be able to hold more than the maximum native int size:

```
#[cfg(target_pointer_width = "16")]
type LargeInt = u32;

#[cfg(target_pointer_width = "32")]
type LargeInt = u64;

#[cfg(target_pointer_width = "64")]
type LargeInt = u128;
```

However, while looking into this, I came across [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41896462/how-to-check-in-rust-if-architecture-is-32-or-64-bit#comment70979125_41896499). It gives an example of an architecture where the native int size is *different* from the pointer width. Thus, my solution will not work for all architectures. Another potential solution would be to write a build script which codegens a small module which defines `LargeInt` based on the size of a `usize` (which we can acquire like so: `std::mem::size_of::<usize>()`.) However, this has the same problem as above, since [`usize` is based on the pointer width](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29592369/1526155) as well. A final obvious solution is to simply keep a map of native int sizes for each architecture. However, this solution is inelegant and doesn't scale well, so I'd like to avoid it.

So, my questions: is there a way to find the target's native int size, preferably before compilation, in order to reduce runtime overhead? Is this effort even worth it? That is, is there likely to be a significant difference between using the native int size as opposed to the pointer width?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's generally hard (or impossible) to get compilers to emit optimal code for BigNum stuff, that's why https://gmplib.org/ has its low level primitive functions (`mpn_...` [docs](https://gmplib.org/manual/Low_002dlevel-Functions.html)) hand-written in assembly for various target architectures with tuning for different *micro*-architecture, e.g. https://gmplib.org/repo/gmp/file/tip/mpn/x86_64/core2/mul_basecase.asm for the general case of multi-limb * multi-limb numbers.  And https://gmplib.org/repo/gmp/file/tip/mpn/x86_64/coreisbr/aors_n.asm for `mpn_add_n` and `mpn_sub_n`  (Add OR Sub = aors), tuned for SandyBridge-family which doesn't have partial-flag stalls so it can loop with `dec/jnz`.

Understanding what kind of asm is optimal may be helpful when writing code in a higher level language.  Although in practice you can't even get close to that so it sometimes makes sense to use a different technique, like only using values up to 2^30 in 32-bit integers (like CPython does internally, getting the carry-out via a right shift, see [the section about Python in this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/237690/bigint-class-in-c/237764#237764)).  In Rust you do have access to `add_overflow` to get the carry-out, but using it is still hard.

For practical use, writing Rust bindings for GMP is probably your best bet, unless that already exists.

Using the largest chunks possible is very good; on all current CPUs, `add reg64, reg64` has the same throughput and latency as `add reg32, reg32` or `reg8`.  So you get twice as much work done per unit.  And carry propagation through 64 bits of result in 1 cycle of latency.

(There are alternate ways to store BigInteger data that can make SIMD useful; @Mysticial explains in [Can long integer routines benefit from SSE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8866973).  e.g. 30 value bits per 32-bit int, allowing you to defer normalization until after a few addition steps.  But every use of such numbers has to be aware of these issues so it's not an easy drop-in replacement.)

---

In Rust, **you probably want to just use `u64` regardless of the target**, unless you really care about small-number (single-limb) performance on 32-bit targets.  Let the compiler build u64 operations for you out of `add` / `adc` (add with carry).

The only thing that might need to be ISA-specific is if `u128` is not available on some targets.  You want to use 64 * 64 => 128-bit full multiply as your building block for multiplication; if the compiler can do that for you with `u128` then that's great, especially if it inlines efficiently.

See also discussion in comments under the question.

One stumbling block for getting compilers to emit efficient BigInt addition loops (even inside the body of one unrolled loop) is writing an add that takes a carry input and produces a carry output.   Note that `x += 0xff..ff + carry=1` needs to produce a carry out even though `0xff..ff + 1` wraps to zero.  So in C or Rust, `x += y + carry` has to check for carry out in both the `y+carry` and the `x+=` parts.

It's really hard (probably impossible) to convince compiler back-ends like LLVM to emit a chain of adc instructions. An add/adc is doable when you don't need the carry-out from adc.  Or probably if the compiler is doing it for you for `u128.overflowing_add`

Often compilers will turn the carry flag into a 0 / 1 in a register instead of using `adc`.  You can hopefully avoid that for at least pairs of `u64` in addition by combining the input u64 values to u128 for `u128.overflowing_add`.  That will hopefully not cost any asm instructions because a `u128` already has to be stored across two separate 64-bit registers, just like two separate `u64` values.

So combining up to `u128` could just be a local optimization for a function that adds arrays of `u64` elements, to get the compiler to suck less.

Comment: Update: new-enough Clang / LLVM can actually emit a proper chain of `adc` instructions from pure C++ source using stuff like `carry = (tmp < carry) + (dst[i] < tmp);`, with carry-in and carry-out from the same instruction.  The same set of logical operations might work in Rust.

Answer (score 1):

In my library [ibig](https://crates.io/crates/ibig) what I do is:

1. Select architecture-specific size based on `target_arch`.
2. If I don't have a value for an architecture, select 16, 32 or 64 based on `target_pointer_width`.
3. If `target_pointer_width` is not one of these values, use 64.

Comment: So on ILP32 ABIs on 64-bit machines (like Linux [x32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI), or AArch64 [ILP32](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.1.0/gcc/AArch64-Options.html)), you end up picking 32.  Avoiding that was kind of the point of the question.  But given that there's no easy way to do better, yes many people do what you're doing.

Comment: @PeterCordes That is incorrect. I just tried it with the x32 target (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnux32) and it selected 64 bits. "target_arch=x86_64" and therefore it selected 64 bits in step 1.

Comment: Oh I see, I misunderstood what you were saying, that you special-cased some known architectures.

Comment: Thank you for your comment though - it helped me realize I need to add support for other architectures to my list such as AArch64, even though I don't have specialized code for them, just to select optimal bit size.